# Angular passing event data doesn't log correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have the component favorite for the "add to favorites" functionality.

I have the next code in favorite.component.ts (only lines for emitting event)

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

 @Input() isFavorite = false;

 this.change.emit({ newValue: this.isFavorite });
```

I have the next code in app.component.html:

```
<favorite [isFavorite]="post.isFavorite" (change)="favButtonChanged($event)"></favorite>
```

And the next one in app.component.ts:

```
favButtonChanged(eventArgs: { newValue: boolean }) {
    console.log("Favorite changed", + eventArgs);
  }
```

The idea is that everytime the button changes (toggles color and html), this event to log in the console "Favorite changed" + 0/1 (a boolean value).
It logs: Favorite changed NaN.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `eventArgs` is an object which will get `NaN` due to `+` you need write `eventArgs.newValue` which is boolean value & get converted into 1/0
Please try the below code

`console.log("Favorite changed ", +eventArgs.newValue)`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `console.log("Favorite changed", + eventArgs);`

There's a comma `,` so you're passing two parameters to `console.log` and the second parameter is `+ eventArgs` which tries to convert `eventArgs` into a number.

As you declared, `eventArgs` is clearly not a number (`NaN` means Not a Number) so the conversion (from the `+` sign) fails.

You might want to remove that `+`.